# how can I read from an uploaded text file

Tags: php, file-get-contents

when I upload a file then how can I read it's content,, and how can I know the location of it
I know that I can use the `file_get_contents` but I don't know how to use it

Comment: Can't you parse the content while uploading the file?

Comment: you're post doesn't give any leads, no idea how the file gets uploaded or whatsoever.

Comment: RTFM: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Clearifications such task would require you to use a server side programming language like PHP; how to open, read, and close a file on the server.

// upload file with a button name: upload_file
$fileContent = file_get_contents($_FILES['upload_file']['tmp_name']);

//Path to your file:
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $tmp = $_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'];
    $name = $_FILES['filename']['name'];


    //Can be any full path, just don't end with a /. That will be added in in the path variable
    $uploads_dir = '/path/to/your/file.txt';

    $path = $uploads_dir.'/'.$name;

    if(move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path)){
        $msg='". $name ."';


// PHP Open File - fopen()

A better method to open files is with the fopen() function. This function gives you more options than the readfile() function.
The first parameter of fopen() contains the name of the file to be opened and the second parameter specifies in which mode the file should be opened. The following example also generates a message if the fopen() function is unable to open the specified file:
Example
<?php
$myfile = fopen("webdictionary.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
echo fread($myfile,filesize("webdictionary.txt"));
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

After submit you can get every information from the superglobal $_FILES that will always return "name", "type", "size", "tmp_name", "error":

```
Array (
    [file_input_name] => Array (
        // the name of the uploaded file
        [name] => uploaded_file.jpg

        // the type of the uploaded file
        [type] => image/jpeg

        // the name of the temporary copy of the file stored on the server
        [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpcOGiTD

        // the error code resulting from the file upload
        [error] => 0

        // the size in bytes of the uploaded file
        [size] => 766379
    )
)
```

you can move it to somewhere else with another name using [move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) and then use [file_get_content](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

`echo file_get_contents($_FILES['file_input_name']['tmp_name']);`

NOTE: the above is an example of single file upload. in case of multiple file upload you need to specify the file you want to view (`[0]`, `[1]` ...):

`echo file_get_contents($_FILES['file_input_name']['tmp_name'][1]);`

Answer (score 0):

please have a look at the function reference **[here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)**.

you have to use something like:

```
$content = file_get_contents("/path/to/your/file.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$fileContent = file_get_contents($_FILES['upload_file']['tmp_name']);
```

**EDIT:** also,read this tutorial [click](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php)